# What does "Idle Wake Ups" indicate in the Mavericks activity monitor?

Tags: osx-mavericks, process-monitoring

The activity monitor for Mavericks running on my 2013 MacBook Pro Retina lists a column "Idle Wake Ups" that is new to me, and Google and Apple Support Forum searches were unrevealing as to what it is telling me. I would welcome any advice about this measure and how I can use it to assess the activity of various processes.

Comment: Just guessing, maybe it's counting how many times it has woken up after it went to sleep because it was idling for some time? What values do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. The numbers range from the single digits to 1200+.

Answer (score 8):

According to Intel an Idle Wake Up is the

> Number of times a thread caused the system to wake up from idleness to
>   begin executing the thread.

Source: [Idle Wake-ups (Intel.com)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/458474)

Answer (score 7):

Mavericks performs some advanced [timer coalescing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timer_coalescing) to reduce power consumption.  Apple claims up to a 72% reduction in CPU activity.  I think (but am still searching for written proof) that `Idle Wake Ups` is the number of times the CPU leaves the idle-state per quanta of time.  I'm not sure what that quanta is (probably one second).

You can read more about Maverick's power savings at Ars Technica's excellent [review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/os-x-10-9/1/#introduction) of OSX 10.9 (page 12, "Energy Savings").

Comment: You mention Mavericks specifically: Is this to say that Yosemite and beyond are less optimal in power saving than Mavericks?

Comment: At the time he commented Mavericks was the latest. Later versions also had it and probably improved on it even.

Comment: I really wish Activity Monitor would specify the quanta of time, e.g. "Idle Wake Ups/sec" or similar. I wonder if the quanta is based on the update frequency.